# PDO - Number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

I have this code, I am running from a cronjob. Although, I get this error:

***SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens***

This is my  code:

```
$TIME_TO_CLICK = (int) date('i');
$HOUR_TO_CLICK = date("H");

if($TIME_TO_CLICK <= 20){
    $QUERY_WHERE = "`click_hour` = '$HOUR_TO_CLICK' AND `click_minute` BETWEEN 1 AND 20";
} else if($TIME_TO_CLICK > 20 && $TIME_TO_CLICK <= 40){
    $QUERY_WHERE = "`click_hour` = '$HOUR_TO_CLICK' AND `click_minute` BETWEEN 20 AND 40";
} else if($TIME_TO_CLICK > 40 && $TIME_TO_CLICK < 60){
    $QUERY_WHERE = "`click_hour` = '$HOUR_TO_CLICK' AND `click_minute` BETWEEN 40 AND 60";
} else {        
    $QUERY_WHERE = "`click_hour` = '$HOUR_TO_CLICK'";
}

$QUERY_XEON = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `xeon_users_rented` WHERE $QUERY_WHERE;");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only did a **Prepare** Should still need to execute the query with some data

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number     of tokens
```

This means that you didn't provide enough info in the query.
Try changing

```
$dbh->prepare
```

to

```
$dbh->query
```